# Escribir diccionario en archivo de texto

Tags: python, archivo, diccionarios

Hola estoy intentando escribir un diccionario, con datos de nombre y de telefono, en un archivo de texto y no lo puedo lograr. Mi diccionario es del tipo: agenda={"Juan":14253 , "Mariano": 24875 , "Marcos":65232} y lo que hice fue esto:

```
agenda={"Juan":14253 , "Mariano": 24875 , "Marcos":65232}
agendaarchivo=open("agendaarchivo.txt", "w")
for nombre,agenda[nombre] in agenda:
    agendaarchivo.write(nombre+":"+agenda[nombre]+"\n")

agendaarchivo.close()
```

Y me salta el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\final compu\error\prue.py", line 4, in 
<module>
for nombre,agenda[nombre] in agenda:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Donde has definido nombre?, Ademas como quieres que se guarden los datos?

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta

Comment: Use "nombres" para referirme a las claves de mi diccionario. No funciona asi? Quiero que se guarden los datos en un archivo de texto, cada par clave-valor uno abajo del otro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu debes de iterar a traves de .`items()`, este retorna la llave y el valor.

```
agenda={"Juan":14253 , "Mariano": 24875 , "Marcos":65232}
with open("agendaarchivo.txt", "w") as agendaarchivo:
    for nombre, valor  in agenda.items():
        agendaarchivo.write("%s %s\n" %(nombre, valor))
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! Ahi me salio